# Binding a viewmodel to a listview

Tags: listview, mvvm, kendo-ui, single-page-application

I'm testing the single page application (SPA) and MVVM features of Kendo UI, but I'm having some problems to bind a Viewmodel to a listview which is the content of on of the pages...

What I have so far is:

```
<div id="app">
    <button data-bind="click: gotopage1">Page 1</button>
    <button data-bind="click: gotopage2">Page 2</button>
    <button data-bind="click: gotopage3">Page 3</button>
</div>

<script id="page1" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul id="listView1" data-bind="source: photossource"></ul>
</script>

<script id="page2" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    //content of page 2
</script>

<script id="page3" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    //content of page 3
</script>

<script id="layout" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <header></header><section id=content></section><footer></footer>
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="templatelistitem">
    <div class="item">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: this }" />
    </div>
</script>
<script>
    var set1 = new Array();
    var set2 = new Array();
    var set3 = new Array();

    //fill the arrays... they are just strings to put on the `src` attribute of the `img`

    var appViewModel = new kendo.observable({
        gotopage1: function () {
            router.navigate("/");
    },
        gotopage2: function () {
            router.navigate("/page2");
    },
        gotopage3: function () {
            router.navigate("/page3");
    }
    });
    kendo.bind($("#app"), appViewModel);

    var pageViewModel = new kendo.observable({
        photossource: set1
    });

    var page1 = new kendo.View("#page1");
    var page2 = new kendo.View("#page2");
    var page3 = new kendo.View("#page3");

    var layout = new kendo.Layout("#layout");

    var router = new kendo.Router();

    router.route("/", function () {
        pageViewModel.photossource = set1;
        layout.showIn("#content", page1);
    });

    router.route("/page2", function () {
        pageViewModel.photossource = set2;
        layout.showIn("#content", page2);
    });

    router.route("/page3", function () {
        pageViewModel.photossource = set3;
        layout.showIn("#content", page3);
    });

    $(function () {
        router.start();
        layout.render($("#app"));
        layout.showIn("#content", page1);
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#listView1").kendoListView({
            template: kendo.template($("#templatelistitem").html())
        });
        kendo.bind($("#listView1"), pageViewModel);
    });
</script>
```

I need to bind the `pageViewModel` to the `listview1` of page1. This `pageViewModel` will be shared for the 3 pages.

This is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined    in
>   kendo.web.min.js:12

My main questions are:

- How should I bind the viewmodel to the listview?
- I need to set the DataSource of the listview?
- How I reference the `photossource` in the template of the list item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/bXXPV/15/) solution without the exception, I believe the functionality as as you expected.

I changed quite few things and I am not saying all of the changes are necessary, but hopefully this example will lead you towards final solution.

1) [views from template](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/spa/view#creating-a-view-from-script-template) is done differently.( I did hard code.)

```
 var index = new kendo.View('index');
```

2) listview for MVVM usage should be created in a following [way](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/mvvm.html)

3) as already mentioned, you should use model.set(key,value) with your observables

```
pageViewModel.set("photossource", set1)
```

4) keep an eye at the order you are initializing controls

Answer (score 2):

Using the Kendo UI View essentially eliminates the need to call kendo.bind. The recommended way is to assign a [ViewModel to the view](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/spa/view#mvvm-integration). Afterwards, you can populate its photossource field when necessary. By the way, any operations performed on the view model should be done via the set and get methods.